# "A stable connection to the server could not be established"

Tags: swift, imap, mailcore2

I trying to connect to Google with OAuth2. I have got access_token and user email. Here is not problem.

```
let singleton: Singleton = Singleton.sharedInstance 
singleton.session.authType = MCOAuthType.XOAuth2 // session:IMAPSession
singleton.session.OAuth2Token = singleton.accessToken
singleton.session.username = singleton.email
singleton.session.hostname = "imap.gmail.ru"
singleton.session.port = 993
singleton.session.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.StartTLS
```

Next step i create fetch operation and get an error

```
let requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Headers  | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Flags | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind.Structure
    let uids = MCOIndexSet(range: MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX))
    let folder = "INBOX"

    let fetchOperation = singleton.session.fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder(folder, requestKind: requestKind, uids: uids)
    fetchOperation.start { (error, fetchedMessages, vanishedMessages) -> Void in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Error: \(error)") // this line return me error
        }
```

> Error: Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo=0x7f9e260036b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}
>   Error: Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo=0x7f9e23c46c00 {NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}

what could be the problem?

Comment: The correct hostname is `imap.gmail.com` and not `imap.gmail.ru`.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà , I fixed it yesterday. But i get new error:Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials. 
i've tried to change port and connectionType but after that i again get:A stable connection to the server could not be established

Comment: "Unable to authenticate" is probably the correct error message. It means that you could connect to Gmail servers. You just need to check on your OAuth2 authentication and use connection loggers on the imap session to debug your stuff.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Can the problem be in my URL request?

`let url = NSURL(string:(NSString(format: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",client_id,callback,scope,visibleactions)))
        self.webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!)) `

Comment: I can't advise on issue related to OAuth2, only with mailcore.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I am using the same IMAP session settings as mentioned by OP, but still get "A stable connection to the server could not be established." sometimes. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Those lines show be fixed to `singleton.session.hostname = "imap.gmail.com"
singleton.session.port = 993
singleton.session.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS`

Comment: I'm having same problem because i didn't have gmail access. Try same code with an internet with complete access.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code guys:

```
    var smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
    smtpSession.hostname = "xxxxxxxx"
    smtpSession.username = "xxxxxxx"
    smtpSession.password = "xxxxxxxx"
    smtpSession.port = 8465
    smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.SASLPlain
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
    smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
        if data != nil {
            if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
            }
        }
    }

    var builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
    builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Rool", mailbox: "xxxxxxx@hxxxx.com")]
    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Matt R", mailbox: "xxxxxx@sxxxxxx.com")
    builder.header.subject = "My message"
    builder.htmlBody = "<h3>This is a test message!</h3>"

    let rfc822Data = builder.data()
    let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperationWithData(rfc822Data)
    sendOperation.start { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error sending email: \(error)")
        } else {
            NSLog("Successfully sent email!")
        }
    }
```

PS: I used this code for SMTP2GO and It's working flawlessly, just make sure you're using the right port.